# replace string under multiple if conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'items': ['countryName', 'stateName', 'currencyName', 'companyName'],
        'code': ['NK', 'NK', 'NK', 'NK']
     })
print(df)

          items code
0   countryName   NK
1     stateName   NK
2  currencyName   NK
3   companyName   NK
```

How can transform NK under several conditions, for instance, if its items is "countryName", change NK to North Korea, if its items is "stateName", change NK to "North Kingstown" so on and so forth. Please note this is only part of dataframe. Thanks.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'items': ['countryName', 'stateName', 'currencyName', 'companyName'],
        'code': ['North Korea', 'North Kingstown', 'Norwegian krone', 'Northrup-King']
     })
print(df)
          items             code
0   countryName      North Korea
1     stateName  North Kingstown
2  currencyName  Norwegian krone
3   companyName    Northrup-King
```

Comment: you need to have a dictionary to look and map the data from..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.where on the DF. It's a bit dirty and I'm sure someone else can give you a cleaner solution but it works.

```
df['code'] = np.where((df['code'] == 'NK') & (df['items'] == 'countryName'),
                      'North Korea',
                       df['code'])

df['code'] = np.where((df['code'] == 'NK') & (df['items'] == 'stateName'),
                      'North Kingstown',
                       df['code'])
... add the rest of the examples
```

How does it work:

- np.where((condition one) & (condition two) & (more conditions)...
- value to set for column 'code' if conditions are met, e.g. North Korea
- keep old value (NK) if conditions are not met

**EDIT**: Addition of simple dynamic version

```
replace_dict = {'North Korea':['NK','countryName'],'North Kingstown':['NK','stateName']}

for key in replace_dict.keys():
    df['code'] = np.where((df.code == replace_dict[key][0]) & (df['items'] == replace_dict[key][1]),
                          key,
                          df['code'])
```

Comment: what if you have a huge data? do you keep assigning the values to each condition.. ??

Comment: You could make it dynamic e.g. by storing the replacement value as dictionary key and the conditions as dictionary values and loop over the dictionary. Probably works well if you always look at the same columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can store both the key and the values in  2 different dfs, probably in an excel sheet and read it directly from there using `pd.read_excel(file)`

If we name them `df` and `df1` :

df:

```
     code            items
0    NK              countryName 
1    NK              stateName 
2    NK              currencyName 
3    NK              companyName
```

df1:

```
     code               items
0    North Korea      countryName 
1    North Kingstown  stateName 
2    Norwegian krone  currencyName 
3    Northrup-King    companyName
```

Then:

```
df = df.merge(df1,on='items').drop('code_x', axis=1)
df.columns=['items','code']
```

This would save a lot of lines of code i think..?

Comment: `df.merge(df1,how='inner',on='items')` should be `df.merge(df1,on='items')`, because `inner` is defaut value

Comment: if it's massive data set, having two data frames can be tedious.

Comment: @jezrael : yes, didnt notice that i put that in my code. :p Thanks. :) btw what do you suggest here ?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'items': ['countryName', 'stateName', 'currencyName', 'companyName'],
        'code': ['NK', 'NK', 'NK', 'NK']
     })

country_value = {'NK': "North Korea"}
state_value = {'NK': 'North Kingstown'}
currency_value = {'NK' : 'Norwegian Krone'}
company_value = {'NK': 'Northrup-king'}

def pair(x):
    if x['items'] == 'countryName':
        x['code'] = country_value[x['code']]
    elif x['items'] == 'stateName':
        x['code'] = state_value[x['code']]
    elif x['items'] == 'currencyName':
        x['code'] = currency_value[x['code']]
    elif x['items'] == 'companyName':
        x['code'] = company_value[x['code']]

    return x


df.apply(pair, axis = 1)
```

This way you can add many country, state etc key value pairs.